# Unity Vuforia: IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm getting this error when compiling for Android.
So far the only info I found was at: https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/77
But nothing about how to solve the issue.
I will appreciate any help to solve the issue.

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GradlePropertiesParser+<>c.<FromString>b__3_1 (System.String v) (at <e2ac827c108347a08067e2bd69c6ad84>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (TSource[] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[T] comparer) (at <7bdabb6dfbaa4804838c76fbb93968d4>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[T] comparer) (at <7bdabb6dfbaa4804838c76fbb93968d4>:0)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Func`2[T,TResult] keySelector, System.Func`2[T,TResult] elementSelector) (at <7bdabb6dfbaa4804838c76fbb93968d4>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GradlePropertiesParser.FromString (System.String content) (at <e2ac827c108347a08067e2bd69c6ad84>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.GradlePropertiesParser.FromFile (System.String path) (at <e2ac827c108347a08067e2bd69c6ad84>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PostProcessAndroidBuild.ParseGradleProperties (System.String projectPath) (at <e2ac827c108347a08067e2bd69c6ad84>:0)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PostProcessAndroidBuild.OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject (System.String path) (at <e2ac827c108347a08067e2bd69c6ad84>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.ProcessGenerateProjectCallbacks.OnGeneratePlatformProjectPostprocess (System.String path, System.Boolean strict) (at <3c54bb7f2c3e4782b3adbd9c545b57b8>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Unity - Vuforia. Compiling for Android.
```

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a solution?